# Relation between kernel.img and /boot/overlay/

Tags: boot

I'm looking to dual boot between two root partitions.
I want to upgrade the other partition and then modify `/boot/cmdline.txt` to reboot on the newly upgraded partition.

There can be different kernel versions on the two root partitions.

In `/boot/config.txt` I can configure the path to `kernel8.img`

```
kernel=part2/kernel8.img
```

where part2 is a folder on the boot partition.

I assume the overlay folder must match the build of `kernel8.img`.

Where do I place the `overlay` folder? in `/boot/overlay` or `/boot/part2/overlay` ?

Can the overlay location be customized?

Comment: Maybe `overlay_prefix`? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md

Comment: @Dirk thanks, I made use of `os_prefix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solutions so far*
The goal is to make the system upgrade as atomic as possible.
Before these steps a new full Linux system is unpacked onto a separate partition that will be referenced in cmdline.txt below.

1. Create a folder for new update: `/boot/linux2`
2. Copy the following files from `/boot/linux2`

   /boot/*.dtb

   /boot/overlay/

   /boot/kernel*.img
   /boot/cmdline.txt
3. Update `/boot/linux2/cmdline.txt` to include the path to the root partition. I use these rather than the GUID version to make sure it works across multiple instances.

   ... `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` ...
4. Critical step, update `/boot/config.txt`

   Add the line:

   `os_prefix=linux1/`
5. Reboot

**Notes**

In addition to step 4 above there is also a few more critical steps in updating all files directly under /boot/ , I have no solution for this so far.

Comment: Although this answer works as described there are still files directly in /boot that would need to be shared between dual booting. In the end I decided to use dual boot partitions which was not trivial but that's a different question..